# how to view logs nlog from web app in azure

Tags: azure, botframework, nlog

I am using nlog to log messages in a file. Now I need to integrate it to Azure. I tried using application insights but it is not working. I need to log the request & response object. I also tried logging to Log stream but that also didn't work.

Program.cs:

```cs
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
           WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
               .UseApplicationInsights()
           .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
           {
               var appInsightKey = hostingContext.Configuration["InstrumentationKey"];
               logging.AddApplicationInsights("InstrumentationKey");
             
               logging.AddFilter<Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>
                                ("", LogLevel.Information)
                      .AddFilter<Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>
                       ("Microsoft", LogLevel.Error);
               //logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));

               //// Enable NLog as one of the Logging Provider
               //logging.AddNLog();
           })
```

Appsetting.json:

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }

  },
  "MicrosoftAppId": "2f71****-****-****-****-********ba89",
  "MicrosoftAppPassword": "123456",
  "ScmType": "None",
  "MiddlewareApiURL": "https://mbei.vmware.com:9090/oasis-chat/qa/api/v1/teams/action",
  "InstrumentationKey": "da55****-****-****-****-********16f0",
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "da55****-****-****-****-********16f0"
  }
}
```

CS class:

```cs
public class OasisBot : ActivityHandler
    {
        private IConfiguration _config;
        private ILogger<OasisBot> _logger;
        public OasisBot(IConfiguration config, ILogger<OasisBot> logger)
        {
            _config = config;
            _logger = logger;
        }
        protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            try
            {
                
                var requestJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(turnContext.Activity);
                _logger.LogInformation("Request Object:" + requestJson.ToString());
```

Comment: Usually Azure Log Stream will capture anything you write to Console (or System.Diagnostics.Trace). Maybe use NLog JsonLayout together with NLog ConsoleTarget ?

Comment: tried tehse both but didnt work:_logger.LogDebug("Request Object:" + requestJson.ToString());
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Test");

Answer (score 0):

It's generally not a good idea to post your app credentials on stackoverflow. I'm not sure if you've already changed them before posting. It might be a good idea to remove or obfuscate them.

Anyway to answer you question. You can use App Insights working by doing the following:

remove this code from Program.cs

```
.UseApplicationInsights()
.ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
{
    var appInsightKey = hostingContext.Configuration["InstrumentationKey"];
    logging.AddApplicationInsights("InstrumentationKey");

    logging.AddFilter<Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>
            ("", LogLevel.Information)
        .AddFilter<Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>
            ("Microsoft", LogLevel.Error);
    //logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));

    //// Enable NLog as one of the Logging Provider
    //logging.AddNLog();
})
```

Add the following code to the ConfigureServices in startup Startup.cs

```
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
services.AddLogging(logging =>
{
    logging.AddApplicationInsights();

    logging.AddFilter<Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>
            ("", LogLevel.Information)
        .AddFilter<Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>
            ("Microsoft", LogLevel.Error);
});
```

And add the following to your appsettings.json

```
"ApplicationInsights": {
  "InstrumentationKey": "yourinstrumentationkey"
}
```

replace yourinstrumentationkey with your instrumentation key from azure.

More information on configuring application insights and where it looks for your instrumentation key is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core